# require_once substitui html

Tags: php, mvc

Eu tenho uma `view` com `require_once` para um controller, porém fazendo o uso do `require_once` o meu código html simplesmente some. Seguem os prints do código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Controller]

Comment: Se possivel, pegue o código, e poste aqui, fica mais fácil para ajudar

Comment: Faltou fechar parênteses e o ponto e vírgula depois de $_PC. Além disso suas tags de script precisam ser fechadas com </script>. Outra consideração é que achei estranho você chamar uma linha e depois passar um resultset, mesmo não sabendo o que seu código faz, o normal é você iterar um resultset num loop lendo linha a linha. Sugiro que você ligue a exibição de erros do PHP ou configure seu servidor de desenvolvimento para sempre exibir erros.